# Cordova 6.0.0 : Android - Delay in Calendar widget

Tags: android, cordova, calendar

I recently branched the working copy of my application to test it with "Cordova 6.0.0". Works smoothly in BB10, iOS and android. However the native "Calendar widget for Android" has changed to the newer one, which is definitely better looking but very slow in term of performance.( Anyone facing the same ? )

Any suggestion to improve the performance of the same (OR) is there any way to revert back to the previous calendar widget?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a lot, finally found that giving a min and max to the input field date helps. There is no delay anymore.

```
<input type="date" name="startDate" min="2015-01-01" max="2099-12-31" v-model="startDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one way you have to change your platform to previous version.